# Dynamic percentage-based width in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, grid, width

maybe you guys can help me figure this out: I have a Dictionary and an ItemsControl that is binded to that dictionary. The Key of each entry determines the content of each Item in the ItemsControl and the Value determines the width of each Item. The big problem with this: The width is a percentage value, so it tells me that, for example, my Item needs to be 20% of its parent in size.

How can I achieve this?
I know Grids are able to work with star-based widths, but since I have to define the GridDefinition at the beginning of the Grid I cannot do this in the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate.

Current code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Distribution}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"> 
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid IsItemsHost="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- I NEED THIS TO BE A CERTAIN PERCENTAGE IN WIDTH -->
                <Label Content="{Binding Key.Text}" Foreground="{Binding Key.Color}"/> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Any ideas on this? Is there any elegant way to solve this?

Thanks!

*Clarifications*: The percentage is supposed to be based  on the ItemControls parent!

*And another one*: Each item is supposed to be one column of the grid, not a row. So I need all the items to be next to each other in the same row.

**The solution**:

Thanks for your help, this problem can be solved by using Multibinding and Binding to the ActualWidth of the ItemsControl. This way, whenever the ItemsControl changes in size, the Items change as well. A Grid is not needed. This solution only creates a relative width, but the same solution can of course be applied to the height of the items. This is a short version, for a more thorough explanation see down below:

*XAML*:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Distribution}" Name="itemsControl"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Key.Text}" 
                       Foreground="{Binding Key.Color}">
                    <Label.Width>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Value"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="itemsControl"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Label.Width>
                </Label>  
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

*Converter*:

```
class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //[1] contains the ItemsControl.ActualWidth we binded to, [0] the percentage
        //In this case, I assume the percentage is a double between 0 and 1
        return (double)value[1] * (double)value[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And that should do the trick!

Comment: 20% of what parent?  The parent of the ItemsControl, Label, or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to define the GridDefinition at the beginning of the Grid?"  You could define your grid in the `DataTemplate` instead - it doesn't need to be in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

Comment: Hi. See my edit, the 20% is supposed to be 20% of the ItemControls parent (or the labels parent. Since I can make the Labels parent Stretch in both directions it would be the same). As for the beginning of the Grid: Yes, I can define my Grid in the DataTemplate, but then each Item would have its own Grid, which wouldn't work, or am I overseeing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>You can implement `IValueConverter`</s>.

**UPDATE**.

`MultiBinding` will help you. Here's the sample:

1) xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="114" Width="404">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:RelativeWidthConverter x:Key="RelativeWidthConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      x:Name="itemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Margin="5" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Rectangle.Width>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RelativeWidthConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="RelativeWidth"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="itemsControl"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Rectangle.Width>
                    </Rectangle> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

2) converter:

```
public class RelativeWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Double)values[0] * (Double)values[1]) / 100.0;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

3) view model:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
    }

    public Double RelativeWidth
    {
        get { return relativeWidth; }
        set
        {
            if (relativeWidth != value)
            {
                relativeWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RelativeWidth");
            }
        }
    }
    private Double relativeWidth;
}
```

4) code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new[] 
        { 
            new ViewModel { RelativeWidth = 20 },
            new ViewModel { RelativeWidth = 40 },
            new ViewModel { RelativeWidth = 60 },
            new ViewModel { RelativeWidth = 100 },
        };
    }
}
```

`MultiBinding` forces to update binding target, when `ActualWidth` changed.

Comment: This sounded promising, but doesn't seem to work. When the Converter is called, the ActualWidth of the ItemsControl is 0, since it hasn't yet been drawn. Seems like a good direction to me, though.

Comment: Thank you very much, Multibinding worked like a charm! I tried updating the binding manually when the ActualWidth changed, but it didn't work. With multibinding it works fine. Clean and nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting a `Grid` in the `ItemTemplate`. This `Grid` would have 2 columns: 1 for the actual content and one for the empty space. You should be able to bind the width of these columns using your dictionary's `Value`, possibly with the aid of an `IValueConverter`.

If the content needs to be centered, you'd need to create 3 columns, splitting the empty space between columns 0 and 2.

Comment: Don't bind the width, use the SharedSizeGroup property on the ColumnDefinition.

Comment: I think this is of no help to me, see my edit. I need each item to be one column and all the items to be aligned next to each other, therefore I cannot work with spaces, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had a required that couldn't use the Grids.

I created a ContentControl that allows me wrap content to add a dynamic percentage width/height.

```
/// <summary>
/// This control has a dynamic/percentage width/height
/// </summary>
public class FluentPanel : ContentControl, IValueConverter
{
    #region Dependencie Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthPercentageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WidthPercentage", typeof(int), typeof(FluentPanel), new PropertyMetadata(-1, WidthPercentagePropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void WidthPercentagePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        ((FluentPanel)dependencyObject).OnWidthPercentageChange();
    }

    public int WidthPercentage
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(WidthPercentageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WidthPercentageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeightPercentageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeightPercentage", typeof(int), typeof(FluentPanel), new PropertyMetadata(-1, HeightPercentagePropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void HeightPercentagePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        ((FluentPanel)dependencyObject).OnHeightPercentageChanged();
    }

    public int HeightPercentage
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(HeightPercentageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeightPercentageProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void OnWidthPercentageChange()
    {
        if (WidthPercentage == -1)
        {
            ClearValue(WidthProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            SetBinding(WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = Parent, Converter = this, ConverterParameter = true });
        }
    }

    private void OnHeightPercentageChanged()
    {
        if (HeightPercentage == -1)
        {
            ClearValue(HeightProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            SetBinding(HeightProperty, new Binding("ActualHeight") { Source = Parent, Converter = this, ConverterParameter = false });
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)parameter)
        {
            // width
            return (double)value * (WidthPercentage * .01);
        }
        else
        {
            // height
            return (double)value * (HeightPercentage * .01);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```