# How do I specify that a buttons width should be 70% of its height in Windows Phone Xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I want the buttons below to take as much space as available horizontally and the height of the buttons to be 70% of the widths. Should, and probably is simple but I haven't found the solution.

Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="startButton">Start</Button>
    <Button x:Name="stopButton" Grid.Column="1">Stop</Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic percentage-based width in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865042/dynamic-percentage-based-width-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be much difference between normal WPF and Windows-Phone WPF, so try this link:

[Dynamic percentage-based width in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865042/dynamic-percentage-based-width-in-wpf)